# Error when deploy Web API on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a Web API project, and will be deployed on IIS. When I publish the project through VS2012, I always got errors like - Unable to add file 'Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js'.  Access is denied. No file in the package is copied into wwwroot.

But, on the other PC it works perfect.

Can anyone suggest on this?

Thanks
Botem

Comment: Ether the file is not in the correct location, ether did not have permission for read it. Probably the first.

Comment: I resolved this by running the VS2012 as administrator. Seems it's a permission problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by running the VS2012 as administrator. Seems it's a permission problem.